# How do I place div "on" background image?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css

I have a RoR app and I am attempting to add a background image. In my css file that is located in app/assets/stylesheets I have:

```
html{
background-image: (destroyer.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: top;
min-height: 100;
}
```

However, each time I add a div to the homepage html, the image seems to be forced to the bottom on the page. All I want is a full page static background image. For the record, I have changed scroll to fixed in the attachment as well as taken off the min height with no luck.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you add your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these CSS properties to the body, instead of the document itself.

```
body {
   background-image: url('destroyer.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't even realize I didn't have the body tag! Thanks so much!